# How to use preDispatch variables in my controller

Tags: zend-framework, plugins

I am creating custom plugin in zend framework using Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract in the disptach method i am using the following code

```
public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) 

{

    global $serversetting;

        $serversetting = 'S3Server';

 }
```

Now I want to use the value of $serversetting inside my controller

How Can i use them??

Thanks In Advance !!

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyclassController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    private $_serversetting;

    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {
        $this->_serversetting = 'S3Server'; //set
    }

    [...]

    public function otherAction() {

        [...]

        $foo = $this->_serversetting; //get

        [...]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your feed back , i have tried your solutions but it gives an error "Argument 1 passed to AdminController::preDispatch() must be an instance of Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract" becuase of abstract method.